# React increment and decrement array counters in state

Tags: reactjs, arrays, state, counter

I have some trouble trying to figure out why I can't correctly increment/decrement four counters in an array, which is in the app state. The array in the state is this:

```js
...
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      right: 0,
      left: 0,
      up: 0,
      down: 0,
      ...more variables... 
      bank: [0, 0, 0, 0] // <- array with 4 counters set to zero
      };
 }
 ...
```

The application fetches JSON data from a Node.js server, and saves the incoming data in the "left", "right", "up" and "down" vars you can see in the state. I select which counter should be incremented/decremented (which I called 'bank') reading the "left" and "right" JSON data, and increment or decrement with "up" and "down". Those signals are working correctly, but the problem is in the logic I think.
This is the function that handles the bank selection (the counter):

```js
  bankSelection() {
    if (parsedJsonData.right) {
      currentBank += 1;
      if (currentBank > maxBank) { // restart from zero
        currentBank = 0;
      }
    } else if (parsedJsonData.left) {
      currentBank -= 1;
      if (currentBank < 0) { // restart from 3
        currentBank = 3;
      }
    }
  }
```

I don't save the bank value in the state, since it shouldn't be rendered. The problem comes with the increment/decrement function:

```js
  updateCounters() {
    if (parsedJsonData.up) {
      if (this.state.bank[currentBank] < 9) {
        let bankValue = this.state.bank[currentBank] + 1;
        this.setState({ bank: bankValue });
      } else {
        this.setState({ bank: this.state.bank[currentBank] = 0 });
      }
    } else if (parsedJsonData.down) {
      if (this.state.bank[currentBank] > 0) {
        let bankValue = this.state.bank[currentBank] - 1;
        this.setState({ bank: bankValue });
      } else {
        this.setState({ bank: this.state.bank[currentBank] = 9 });
      }
    }
  }
```

I see the React engine complains on line 7 and 14, saying I shouldn't mutate the state directly, but I'm inside a setState function!
Beside this, when I send a JSON formatted like this:

```
{
    "left": 0,
    "right": 0,
    "up": 1,
    "down": 0
}
```

the first time the counter in the first bank is updated correctly and shows value 1, but the second time I get this error in the browser's console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot create property '0' on number '1'
    at App.updateCounters (App.js:145:1)
    at App.js:112:1
```

I tryed so many solutions I'm going crazy, any help would me appreciated...
You can find the [full code here](https://jsfiddle.net/Furio/xen230kt/1/) but bear in mind it's still a work in progress in the render method (the first bank is the only one usable, still testing various solutions).
I hope I gave you all the info to help me fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few problems with your code.

1. `bank`'s value is array. You're trying to change it to integer with `this.setState({ bank: bankValue })`
2. State should be immutable, if you wish to change the value, you need to create a new array and set the `bank` state. Something like this:

```
this.setState({bank: Object.values({...this.state.bank, 1: 100}); // where 1 is the idx where you want to update the value, and 100 is the new value
```

Comment: Correct, my code was full of flaws! Actually I was trying to mutate the state directly, but even worse I was trying to treat an object as it was an array... luckily I solved the problems now. I'll update the code in JsFiddle. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hello there, I'm still having problems in setting the value of one of the array indexes to an integer. The state object is `bank: [0, 0, 0, 0]` and this is how I'm trying to set the value to zero:
`this.setState({ bank: this.state.bank[currentBank] = 0 });`
Of course this raises a warning, so I tryed doing this:
`this.setState({ bank: Object.values({ ...this.state.bank, [currentBank]: 0 }) });`
But in this case the value seems to be set to zero, but is not printed.
Any suggestion?

Comment: I tried this, which makes more sense to me, but still having the same trouble:
`var zeroArray = [...this.state.bank];
 zeroArray[currentBank] = 0;
 this.setState({ bank: zeroArray });`
Still, I can update the counter correctly, but the value 0 is not showed in the console. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I managed to solve the problem.
I managed this using the spread operator and avoiding direct assignment inside the setState method.

```js
updateCounters() {
    if (parsedJsonData.up) {
      if (this.state.bank[currentBank] < 9) {
        // let bankValue = this.state.bank[currentBank] + 1;
        var newArrayUp = [...this.state.bank];
        newArrayUp[currentBank] += 1;
        console.log("array clonato dopo aggiornamento " + [...newArrayUp]);
        this.setState({ bank: [...newArrayUp] }, () => {
          this.forceUpdate();
        });
      } else {
        var zeroArray = [...this.state.bank];
        zeroArray[currentBank] = 0;
        console.log(zeroArray[currentBank]);
        this.setState({ bank: [...zeroArray] });
        this.forceUpdate();
      }
    } else if (parsedJsonData.down) {
      if (this.state.bank[currentBank] > 0) {
        var newArrayDown = [...this.state.bank];
        newArrayDown[currentBank] -= 1;
        console.log("array clonato dopo aggiornamento " + [...newArrayDown]);
        this.setState({ bank: [...newArrayDown] }, () => this.forceUpdate());
      } else {
        var nineArray = [...this.state.bank];
        nineArray[currentBank] = 9;
        console.log(nineArray[currentBank]);
        this.setState({ bank: [...nineArray] }, () => this.forceUpdate());
      }
    }
  }
```

Now I create a copy of the original array, work on it and then pass it to the setState method.
Thanks for suggestions!